# Using Toggleable Tabs in JavaScript Android App

Tags: javascript

I am using an example from w3schools and so far, I haven't been able to get anything to work (besides showing the tabs on load in my app)

I would like to make a simple temperature converter on one tab and a distance converter on another one.. Here is my code below, and i will just say thanks in advance!

```
<body>



        <div class="app">
          <!-- Content wil go here :)-->
           <!-- Tab links -->
      <div class="tab">
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'temperature')">Temperature</button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'distance')">Distance</button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'about')">About</button>
          </div>

          <!-- Tab content -->
          <div id="temperature" class="tabcontent">
            <h3>London</h3>
            <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
          </div>

          <div id="distance" class="tabcontent">
            <h3>Paris</h3>
            <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
          </div>

          <div id="about" class="tabcontent">
            <h3>Tokyo</h3>
            <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}

var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },


    onDeviceReady: function() {
        document.getElementById("temperature").addEventListener("click", this.temperature);
    },


       openCity: function(evt, cityName)
        {

        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }

};

app.initialize();
```